# Where was this scene of 'Highlander: The series' with standing columns shot?

Tags: film-location, highlander

In season 6 episode 3, Duncan meets another immortal in a place with a lot of standing columns which hold up nothing. The episode takes place in France.

[image: Still image from Highlander Season 6 Episode 3, showing Duncan MacLeod and Alex Raven among white pillars]

I haven't found any information about this location. I expect it was either an art installation or something unfinished and might not even exist, 24 years later.

Is there a public record about where this scene was filmed?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This seems to be part of the [Axe Majeur](https://thegoodlifefrance.com/axe-majeur-an-architectural-masterpiece-near-paris/)

> The Axe Majeur is a monumental, immensely grand, work of art. At 3.2km long it is extraordinary despite not being complete according to the original plans. And somehow, despite it’s size, the Axe Majeur on the edge of Paris is hardly known outside of France…

It consists of several parts of which one is "Les Douze colonnes" (The Twelve Columns)...

> This architectural symbol represents a modern and natural urban landscape. The twelve features and the twelve columns symbolise time, the pace of human life and the very planet itself. It is a very modern monument, a shrine almost, to a contemporary 21st. Century France. It is an enormous and impressive feature built to last for all time. The linear positioning of the symbols have been aligned with the Champs de Mars that radiates outwards from the Eiffel tower in the centre of Paris.

[image]

[Google Maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Axe+majeur/@49.0375243,2.0398412,581a,35y,39.29t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x1968c7f88e46e97e!8m2!3d49.0422567!4d2.0377194)

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axe_majeur -> https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axe_majeur#/media/Fichier:Dynamobile_2012_%C3%A0_Cergy.jpg

Comment: "It is an enormous and impressive feature built [out of concrete]."